# How to make my HTML list with many items have less lines?

Tags: javascript, html

So I have 22 different lists with 50-100 items inside. And they take ~25k lines of html code. How to make them take less lines?

For example:

I want this to have only one item in list that repeats many times but with different ids, ids in classicImage/shortyImage(' ') and different images if this is possible

```
<a onclick="showClassic()">
    <div class="classic">
        <img src="images/classic/classic_default.png" class="imgcol2" id="classicimg" style="max-height: 75px; max-width: 150px;" >
        <div class="wname" style="width: 150px;">CLASSIC</div>
    </div>
</a>
<a onclick="showShorty()">
    <div class="shorty">
        <img src="images/shorty/shorty_default.png" class="imgcol2" id="shortyimg">
        <div class="wname" style="width: 150px;">SHORTY</div>
    </div>
</a>

<div class="results">
    <ul id="classicList">
        <li class="collection-item">
            <!-- sets source of image with id="classicimg" to source of image with id classic-avalanche -->
            <a onclick="classicImage('classic-avalanche'); setClassicPrice(1275)">
                <div class="result-container">
                    <div class="result">
                        <img src="images/classic/classic_avalanche.png" class="windowimage" id="classic-avalanche">
                    </div>
                    <p class="skinname">Classic Avalanche</p>
                </div>
            </a>
        </li>
        <li class="collection-item">
            <!-- sets source of image with id="classicimg" to source of image with id classic-default -->
            <a onclick="classicImage('classic-default'); setClassicPrice(0)">
                <div class="result-container">
                    <div class="result">
                        <img src="images/classic/classic_default.png" class="windowimage" id="classic-default">
                    </div>
                    <p class="skinname">Classic Default</p>
                </div>
            </a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>

<div class="results">
    <ul id="shortyList">
        <li class="collection-item">
            <!-- sets source of image with id="shortyimg" to source of image with id shorty-aerosol -->
            <a onclick="shortyImage('shorty-aerosol'); setShortyPrice(0)">
                <div class="result-container">
                    <div class="result">
                        <img src="images/shorty/shorty_aerosol.png" class="windowimage" id="shorty-aerosol">
                    </div>
                    <p class="skinname">Shorty Aerosol</p>
                </div>
            </a>
        </li>
        <li class="collection-item">
            <!-- sets source of image with id="shortyimg" to source of image with id shorty-default -->
            <a onclick="shortyImage('shorty-default'); setShortyPrice(0)">
                <div class="result-container">
                    <div class="result">
                        <img src="images/shorty/shorty_default.png" class="windowimage" id="shorty-default">
                    </div>
                    <p class="skinname">Shorty Default</p>
                </div>
            </a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Create a database table for your *items*. Populate it with the items data. Create a backend route that can accept **Pagination queries**. `/api/items?p=3` or like `/api/items?limit=50&offset=150`

Answer (score 0):

Considering you tagged javascript and html only, i assume you have no backend code to handle the templating.

So my best advice would be to divide those multiple lists into multiple .html file and load them with JS, like this example with jQuery :

```html
<html> 
  <head> 
    <script src="jquery.js"></script> 
    <script> 
    $(function(){
      $("#firstList").load("firstList.html"); 
    });
    </script> 
  </head> 

  <body> 
     <div id="firstList"></div>
  </body> 
</html>
```

Comment: *"just create hundreds of .html files and load them using jQuery's .load()"* **The many problems with it:** 1) not a jQuery question. 2) Documents become hard to maintain. Imagine having to edit way too many files because you decided to slightly change the markup. 3) Load documents instead of data is wasteful 4) Does not provide any mean of *paginated structure*. 5) Cannot change the amount of data 6) Portability: no API, and you're stuck with an unmaintainable codebase and markup 7) Maintenance: remove 40 items from a page and you have to manually shift items from all *N* documents. 8) etc.

Comment: i totally agree but i don't think the OP has any kind of templating or pagination query since he didn't tag any backend language... He only asked about how to reduce the lines, not about how to do it properly otherwise he would have no issues having a kind of paginated rendering etc

Comment: OK, but in such case why not load JSON data from .json files instead? Seems much more flexible.

Comment: you are obviously right but again you assume there is a kind of templating able to eat the json and loop over data, where the OP only asked about reducing html lines and as you said, not even sure he has some jQuery.
To be honest i don't understand the question since this 25k html template must be produced somewhere on a backend with a kind of loop, idk why the OP is not looking about the code producing that